# High energy efficiency through transformers

Tags: transformer, efficiency

We are about to build a large facility, using lots of electricity. The facility is being built in module form, which are copies of one another.

We are unsure of whether the energy efficiency will be better if we use several transformers (5, 12 and 24VDC) to each module or if we should go with a large transformer of each and drag cables to each modules. Is there a way to calculate the energy efficiency? Does it help if the cables/transformers are cooled using fans, thus, lowering the resistance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One large transformer is generally more efficient than two small transformers. It's especially true when the transformers get very small, below 10VA.

However, one large transformer plus some long wiring carrying high current at low voltage could easily be less efficient than two small transformers plus some wire carrying high voltage at low current, it depends on the length and size of the wire. The loss in the wire can be reduced asymptotically to zero by using very thick wire, which is generally not done as very thick wire is expensive.

It will be quite easy to calculate the losses from your expected power consumption, distances between modules, wire size you want to afford, and efficiency data on the transformers you intend to use. Set up a spreadsheet so you can re-run the calculation while changing wire sizes, distances, transformer selections, and compute the cost and power losses for each configuration.